# check if jQuery UI tabs have been initialized (without checking for class)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

Using jQuery UI tabs - and I've written a plugin that integrates with ui tabs.
I've got the plugin setup to initiate jQuery UI tabs if it `.tabs()` hasn't been called, but this just does a simple class check:

```
 if(!$globalTabs.hasClass("ui-tabs")){
    $globalTabs.tabs();
 }
```

But this is problematic, because often to avoid FOUC, developers add in the UI classes to the the tabs to get a better initial render before document.ready.

I could check for a different class, such as `ui-widget1, but wondering if there's another/better way?

Comment: But why do you care if it's been called or not? You can always call .tabs() again without anything bad happening.

Comment: @aquinas - it's usually good practice to avoid making unnecessary calls.

Comment: Agreed, but you're worried about making one (possibly unnecessary) call? Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gBZbd/. I'm calling tabs *1000* times, and it only takes 10 milliseconds. Seems like an awfully big premature optimization to me. @Frédéric Hamidi is absolutely correct in his answer, but AFAIK, this isn't documented anywhere. That code *could* break at any time. Just my two cents of course.

Comment: @aquinas, this is actually documented, see my updated answer.

Comment: Ah ha. I guess I've seen plugins do that but didn't realize it was "officially" sanctioned. Good reference. +1. (But I still think worrying about one call to tabs() is not worth thinking about. :)

Comment: @aquinas - we have a dinosaur of a site - it's huge/enterprise level and I try to minimize calls as much as possible, because our codebase stretches back for years and years, and a ton of developers have had their hand in the pot. So the code is bloated, so I try to refactor and minimize impact as much as possible. Someone's got to be the shepherd of the code...

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can query the attached widget with [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/):

```
if (!$globalTabs.data("tabs")) {
    $globalTabs.tabs();
}
```

This behavior is documented in the [Widget factory](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138135/Widget%20factory) page of jQuery UI's [Development & Planning Wiki](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12137947/FrontPage):

> - Plugin instance accessible via `$( "#something" ).data( "pluginname" )`
>
>   - A reference to a jQuery object containing the DOM element is
>       available as a property of the instance as `this.element`, so it is
>       easy to go back and forth between the object and the element.

**Update:** From jQuery UI 1.9 onwards, [the widget key becomes the widget's fully qualified name, with dots replaced with dashes](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#changed-naming-convention-for-data-keys), as in:

```
if (!$globalTabs.data("ui-tabs")) {
    $globalTabs.tabs();
}
```

Using unqualified names is still supported in 1.9 but is deprecated, and support will be dropped in 1.10.

Comment: +1 the answer. BUT with regard to my comment about premature optimization: running the if statement actually makes the code slower: See: http://jsfiddle.net/gBZbd/ versus http://jsfiddle.net/gBZbd/2/.

Comment: @aquinas, indeed, but the question does not mention performance, so we do not know if it's about speed. The questioner might actually need to know if a widget has been instantiated on an element, for reasons we cannot guess. So, I tried to answer that, just in case :)

Answer (score 3):

somehow it causes some error when i try to check the instance.

i need to reinitialize the tabs and for me a try catch did the trick:

```
try {
    $('.mytabs').tabs('destroy');
} catch (exception) {}
```

and after that just initialize again:

```
$('.mytabs').tabs();
```

Comment: May be due to newer jQuery UI versions, which changed some of the methods such as "data".

Comment: unfortunately i am a little bit limited by having to support ie8...
so updating plugins has to be done very carefully (or better don't update anything :D )